# does team services provide private repositories?

Tags: git, version-control, azure-devops

There is a free team services account for up to 5 users. My question is that, does it give free private repositories? On the site, it says free unlimited git repositories for paid version but nothing about the free version. Please doe let me know.

Thanks

Comment: I asked this question because the keyword "private" is not used for the free account on the visual studio site. It only mentions **"unlimited git repositories"** but not **"unlimited private git repositories"**. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/pricing/ and https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/compare-features/, yes, the free tier has unlimited private git repos.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, VSTS provide private git repositories.

And a VSTS account is free for 5 users to co-work. And it's not limit for you to create git repositories.

Comment: Thanks. I was unable to find the "private" keyword for free account on visual studio site.

Comment: Actually all the git repositories on VSTS are private since others can't visit your account (https://account.visualstudio.com) if you are not set permissions for others.

Comment: Right. It is a valid point. Thanks for clearing that up buddy.